# Issue on UITableViewCell custom class and UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I created a custom class of UITableViewCell with some variables for different state on UIGestureRecognizer.

For exemple :

```
class CustomClass : UITableViewCell {
    var isDisabled : Bool! = false
}
```

I have a swipe gesture to detect that the user want disabled the cell. So when the user swipe, I set my variable "isDisabled" to true.

Everything works fine until here.

But, if the first row has the variable "isDisabled" to true and I scroll in my tableView, the first row load at the bottom of the page has the variable "isDisabled" to true too, but the user don't say that he want this cell disabled.

So, have you any idea how I can solved my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the reusable-cell behavior in `UITableView`?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you declaring your `isDisabled` as an implicitly unwrapped optional when you are instantiating it with a value? Would you ever set it to `nil` for any reason?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you explain is regarding the reuse cells bahaviour of the `UITableView`. You can solve in different ways, I'll try to explain you one of them:

- You can create a collection (`Array`, or something else) of `Bool` for example, with the size of the numbers of cells in your `UITableView` and whenever you detect a swipe gesture mark the position in the array for the `indexPath.row` to `true` or `false` depends of it state. This keep the status of the cells for each index.

I hope this help you.

Comment: You could, of course, reset the `Bool` in `prepareForReuse`, but as Apple explicitly states, you should not use a table view cell for storing state about an item.